# Ошибка авторизации Google+: invalid_request

Tags: php, авторизация, google-api

Вопрос в следующем: как получить `access_token` от Google при авторизации?

Делаю так:

1) получаю параметр `code`:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=мой_id&redirect_uri=мой_url&scope=email profile
```

2) отправляю запрос:

```
    $params = array(
        "code" => $data['code'] ,
        "client_id" => "мой_id" ,
        "client_secret" => "секрет" ,
        "redirect_uri" => "мой_url" ,
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code"
    ) ;
    $url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token' ;
    $token = json_decode(file_get_contents($url . '?' . http_build_query($params)), true) ;
```

Но ответ получаю:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
```

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2):

Вы отправляете GET-запрос, а надо POST. Надо через curl